# Eclipse CDT ignores changes in makefile

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I'm using Eclipse CDT 3.8.1 and have a C++ project using my own makefile.
It was compiling properly, using my own makefile.
Then I made a change to this makefile, which led to an error.
The change was modifying the line

```
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

to

```
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c?=.o)
```

(I did this hoping both the .cpp files and my one .cxx file generated from codesynthesis c++/Tree would be treated the same way.)
This led to the error:

```
No rule to make target 'MyFileFromSOURCES.cpp', needed by all. Stop.
```

Now, the strange part is that after undoing all changes again, cleaning the project and rebuilding it, the same error remains. I am sure the Makefile is exactly the same as when it was working. When creating a new project with the same sources and compiling it again, it will also work.

I don't want to have to create a new project with the same content everytime I make a change of such sort to the makefile. Does anyone know what the cause and/or fix is?

Comment: Did you save the makefile after reverting it to the initial version? And what is MyFileFromSOURCES.cpp? Which rules use it, does this cpp-File exists? If not which rule creates it?. Is it possible that the substring SOURCES relates to the variable $SOURCES and there was an error with the dollar sign?

Comment: yes, everything was saved. it is the first .cpp file in SOURCES. Its real name wasn't relevant to my problem so I just called it that to avoid confusion(not realizing it would instead create it). It exists, and nothing should go wrong with it since everything has been changed back to the way it was before and it works when I put the same files in a new project.

Comment: Maybe it is worth a try to use the makefile directly from the commandline without eclipse. This would eliminate eclipse (and whatever it caches in the workspace) out of the equation.

Comment: Good point. Thank you for your suggestions. I just tried it and it stops working there also. So to make sure I hadn't made a mistake, I imported said project again, compiled it (no problems using the makefile), then made the same change to the makefile, saved, compiled again which resulted in that error. Resetting the makefile (even deleting and using the one from my original project) did nothing to change this. I don't understand since literally the only thing I touched was the makefile, which I reset.